# Resize photos as thumbnail squares like Flickr and Facebook photostreams?

Tags: facebook, thumbnails, photo, flickr, crop

What is the best way to resize photos and create square, same-sized thumbnail pictures for photostreams?  Flickr and Facebook do this, and we would like to emulate this functionality.

Here's an example: http://www.flickr.com/photos/alphageek/233472093/

If you view the photostream on the right hand side (mid page), all the thumbnails are the same size even though the original images vary in size, and most importantly, the thumbnails appear intelligently cropped.

Flickr is able to automatically crop and resize image around the main focus, as opposed to simply resizing the image to thumbnail size (e.g., by setting the image width and height), which would cause the image to look squished and lose the focus of the image.

Comment: As i seen on link you sent all images appears to be cropped to middle, and maybe a bit resampled - so you can see more of picture, but it is not so annoying

Comment: Thanks, SergeS.  How do they do it programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such problems, i always use: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php.

Imagemagick provides a lot of functions for manipulations images.
I take images in a loop and create a large version and a thumbnail-version.

Answer (score 1):

they are doing a resized crop.

if you are using imagemagick to convert it would be the # option like "40x40#" or "90x90#" where the photo will be resized then cropped to maintain aspect ratio while getting as much as possible in the thumbnail.

programmatically it probably goes like this:

1) resize image so that the short side is as specified.
2) crop for the middle so the long side is now also as specified.

Comment: thanks!  is there a way to do this without downloading imagemagick?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  First you need to get a new size keeping aspect ratio intact:

```
CGFloat horizontalRatio = newSize.width/oldSize.width;
CGFloat verticalRatio = newSize.height/oldSize.height;
CGFloat ratio = MAX(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio);
CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(oldSize.width *ratio, newSize.height*ratio)
```

Then you need to redraw your image in the new size (self is your image):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, YES, 0);
    [self drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Then crop to desired size :

```
        CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake ((newImage.size.width - width) / 2, (newImage.size.height - height) / 2, width, height)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(cropRect.size, YES, 0); 
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGRect drawRect = CGRectMake(-cropRect.origin.x, -cropRect.origin.y, self.size.width, self.size.height);
        CGContextClipToRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, cropRect.size.width, cropRect.size.height));
        [self drawInRect:drawRect];
        UIImage* croppedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return croppedImage;
```